# How to call `pod` or 'target' in another script

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

Now I have a function that defined in another ruby file, and I want to call `target` and `pod` function dynamically. like:

```rb
module MyModule

def MyModule.some_function 
  # do something and then
  target "#{result_name}" do 
    pod 'AFNetworking'
  end 
end 

end
```

In podfile:

```rb
required './some_function'

MyModule.some_function
```

Is that available?

Edit: Adding Module for my script file, and when I run `pod install` and there's an error says `unknown method pod in module MyModule`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `define_method :"#{result_name}" do ... end` to do it

For example

```rb
# inside foo.rb
def foo
    define_method :bar do
        puts "bar"
    end
end

#inside main.rb
require_relative "foo" # require_relative  automatically set ./file

foo
bar # puts "bar"
```